# Change special characters to english

Tags: r

I am extracting data from Google Trends with `gtrendsr` and I am facing a problem with German letters.
I have the following word that I need to convert to English: **GroÃŸhÃ¶flein**

I am using `stri_trans_general("GroÃŸhÃ¶flein","latin-ascii")` from `stringi` package but the result is: `"GroAYhA¶flein"`. How can I do this transformation? From the "special" characters to english characters?

Comment: Your original text needs to be in encoding that will preserve your characters. I would suggest you use UTF-8.

Comment: I changed it using Encoding() function! Thanks Roman

Comment: What do you want to see as the transformed data?

Comment: I wanted to see the data transformed with UTF-8 characters. After Roman's suggestion I set the data to UTF-8 with Endoding() and it worked. Thanks G5W